# Itext 7 library replaces text in pdf file, but the selected text is not in the right position

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I'm using the itext 7 library in a java project. In input I have a pdf file in which I cover some words with a white background and replace them with other words, and I insert the result into a new pdf file. Everything works fine, the new pdf has the words I wanted replaced, but if I select all the text and copy it to a notepad, the words I inserted are inserted at the end of each page and not in the correct positions.
This is a piece of my code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

// First step: cleaning entities occurrences
for (ITextArea area : areas) {
    cleanAreaContent(pdfDocument, area);
}

// Second step: adding pseudonym text
for (ITextArea area : areas) {
    Rectangle rect = (Rectangle) area;
    PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(area.getPageNumber() + 1);

    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ITALIC);
    float height = rect.getHeight();
    float width = rect.getWidth();

    Text pseudonym = new Text(area.getPseudonym());
    pseudonym.setFont(font);
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
    try (Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, rect)) {
      Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(pseudonym).setFont(font).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
      canvas.add(paragraph);
      canvas.setProperty(Property.APPEARANCE_STREAM_LAYOUT, false);
      canvas.showTextAligned(paragraph, width / 2, height / 2,TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);      }
  }
  pdfDocument.close();
}
```

Searching online for PDF files produced like this, I noticed that they all have the same problem, so my question is whether it could be a problem with the Itext library?
Thank you.

Comment: *"my question is whether it could be a problem with the Itext library"* - Many copy&paste and text extraction approaches output the text in the order it is drawn by the instructions in the page content stream. Your code first redacts the words you want to replace and then _appends_ instructions to the content stream that draw the replacement words. Consequentially, the replacements your code added are extracted after the regular page content.

Comment: @mlk Is there a way with this approach to add the words to be replaced in the correct position on the page?